# AVFoundation Not recording on IOS 11.3

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, ios11, video-capture

I have tried to record video using AVFoundation, and assign audio input with the session. It is working fine unto IOS 11.2.6 but its throwing error on IOS 11.3 when we are trying to start recording.

```
let videoCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
var videoInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var micInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var cameraDevice:AVCaptureDevice!
var outputURL: URL!
var videoUrl : NSURL!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if !videoCaptureSession.isRunning || hasPlaceCameraOpened {
            self.setCameraSession()
        }
}

func setCameraSession() {

        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            return
        }

        self.cameraPreview.isHidden = true
        videoCaptureSession.sessionPreset = CamResolution // set from MyConstant
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: videoCaptureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize//AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = self.cameraPreview.bounds
        previewLayer.masksToBounds = true
        self.cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        if videoCaptureSession.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh) {
            videoCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        }





        cameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)

        do {

            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
            if videoCaptureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                videoCaptureSession.addInput(videoInput)
            }

        }
        catch let error {
            print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


        do {

            micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone)
            if videoCaptureSession.canAddInput(micInput) {
                videoCaptureSession.addInput(micInput)
            }

        }
        catch let error {
            print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }


        let movieOutput:AVCaptureMovieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        if videoCaptureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
            videoCaptureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

            let connection: AVCaptureConnection? = movieOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

                connection!.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.cinematic
            }
            self.movieOutput = movieOutput
        }
    }

@IBAction func startRecording(sender:UIButton) {
        if !movieOutput.isRecording {
            outputURL = self.tempURL()
            do{
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
            }catch let err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            movieOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
        }
    }

func tempURL() -> URL? {
        guard let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first else {
            return nil
        }
        return (docURL.appendingPathComponent("\(ProjectConstants.strTimestamp).mp4"))
    }
```

And finally implemented delegate methods:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInteractive).async {
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                _ = self.outputURL as URL
            }

            let pathString = outputFileURL.relativePath
            self.videoUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: pathString) as NSURL
            self.videosUrlArray.append(self.videoUrl! as URL)

            do {
                let videoData = try Data.init(contentsOf: outputFileURL)
                self.saveVideoToDocumentDirectory(fileData: videoData)
            } catch let err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Up to IOS 11.2 the only problem I am facing is some time a white screen appears in spite of camera screen but on IOS 11.3 each and every time video is not recorded and throwing error on the delegate methods. I am not understand what is wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note: There may be some editing issue, I am not habituated with this. Please forgive for that.

Comment: Can you please paste the error here?

Comment: Right now no issues occurring, recording normally... Will post if anything odd situation arise.

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing several changes in API...
Maybe you should try with

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)
```

Instead of

```
func capture(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!)
```

I had the same with this not getting called anymore..

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

Had to be replaced by

```
 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

The doc use a mix of both references

```
   @method captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:
     @abstract
        Informs the delegate when all pending data has been written to an output file.

     @param output
        The capture file output that has finished writing the file.
     @param outputFileURL
        The file URL of the file that has been written.
     @param connections
        An array of AVCaptureConnection objects attached to the file output that provided the data that was written to the file.
     @param error
        An error describing what caused the file to stop recording, or nil if there was no error.

     @discussion
        This method is called when the file output has finished writing all data to a file whose recording was stopped, either because startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate: or stopRecording were called, or because an error, described by the error parameter, occurred (if no error occurred, the error parameter will be nil). This method will always be called for each recording request, even if no data is successfully written to the file.

        Clients should not assume that this method will be called on a specific thread.

        Delegates are required to implement this method.
     */
    public func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?)
```